# How can I see the gem value of an item that I do not own?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I can see how many gems an item in my inventory converts to when I turn it into gems. But is there any way to know how many gems I would get for an item I do not own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple search in google would direct you to the ["Gems by Game" section of the Steam Trading Card Wiki](http://steamtradingcards.wikia.com/wiki/Gems_by_Game).

You can both find the value of the cards theirselves and the craftable items (Emoticons, Backgrounds). Additionally the needed amount of gems to craft a booster pack is also displayed.

Keep in mind, that the entries in the wikis aren't displayed dynamically, means that some values might be not up to date. Furthermore I assume that there are many games missing, but the list is very long though.

Very interesting is following, what I copied & pasted from the source above:

> Assuming that `n = # cards in set`, `c = value of single card`, `g = value of emoticon/background`, and `b = gems to craft booster`, any one of the four can be calculated if any two other values are known. This doesn't hold true for every game, but is accurate for the vast majority:
>
> `n = 6000/b`
>
> `n = 2g/c`
>
> `c = bg/3000`
>
> `c = 2g/n`
>
> `g = 3000c/b`
>
> `g = n * c/2`
>
> `b = 6000/n`
>
> `b = g/3000c`

Comment: Have you checked this to make sure this is correct information?

Comment: Please read the post: `This doesn't hold true for every game, but is accurate for the vast majority`

Comment: Haven't come across that site yet. Searched for tags like "steam", "gem", "value", "list", "item". If there is no way to determine the exact gem value of a specific card then this answer is probably the closest I can get. I leave  I accept it in a view days since I am really looking for exact number

Comment: @MennoGouw Its a good question. I knew the site but through your question I read the content closlier and came across the formulas which is very helpful imo :D I for myself didnt find any mistakes in the formulas except mistakes from rounding

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

**Here's a bookmarklet that you can run on the Community Market page for an item to get its gem value:**

```
javascript:var a=g_rgAssets[Object.keys(g_rgAssets)[0]],b=a[Object.keys(a)[0]],c=b[Object.keys(b)[0]],gem_action=c.owner_actions&&c.owner_actions.filter(function(d){return/javascript:GetGooValue/.test(d.link)})[0];if(gem_action){var matches=gem_action.link.match(/javascript:GetGooValue\( '%contextid%', '%assetid%', (\d+), (\d+), \d+ \)/);fetch("https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid="+matches[1]+"&item_type="+matches[2]+"&border_color=0").then(function(d){return d.json()}).then(function(d){alert("This is worth "+d.goo_value+" gems")})["catch"](function(d){return console.error(d)})}else alert("This is worth 0 gems");
```

When you're on the Community Market page for an item, paste this into the URL bar (you might have to retype the `javascript:` portion). You can also save it as a bookmark, which you can just click on to run.

---

## Explanation

As [noted by Wok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/350625/218385), you can get the number of gems an item is worth by passing the appropriate `appid` and `item_type` to this endpoint:

> https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=219890&item_type=16

which in this example corresponds to my favorite profile background from the game [*Antichamber*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/219890/Antichamber/) and returns this response:

```
{"success":1,"goo_value":"80"}
```

But as noted by Wok and an answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889254/3427178), `item_type` isn't exactly predictable and depends on the game and the relative amounts of item types that they have.

### How does the Steam inventory webpage figure out what `item_type` is?

**It's pretty gross.**

When you load your inventory, the webpage makes a few requests (one for each context in that inventory) to get a list of inventory items. These JSON responses contain the `item_type` for each item, but in the worst format possible.

Each inventory object in the `descriptions` array of the JSON response contains an `owner_actions` array, where each object has a `link` and a `name`. `item_type` is stored in that link.

Sticking to the *Antichamber* profile background example, here's the link with its `item_type`:

```
"owner_actions":
[
  {
    "link": "javascript:GetGooValue( '%contextid%', '%assetid%', 219890, 16, 0 )",
    "name": "Turn into Gems..."
  }
]
```

The click events on the Steam inventory page parse out that JavaScript URL to figure out what event handler to run. The function `GetGooValue()` doesn't actually exist.

In case you didn't see it, the third argument to this nonexistent function provides `appid` and the fourth argument provides `item_type`.

*vomits*

### What about items not in your inventory?

The previous web requests depend on a user's inventory, which isn't helpful if you want to find the gem value of some arbitrary item.

However, Community Market pages have a global variable called `g_rgAssets`. Here's a truncated sample for our example:

```
{
  "753":
  {
    "6":
    {
      "6298989828":
      {
        ... [truncated]
        "owner_actions":
        [
          {
            "link": "javascript:GetGooValue( '%contextid%', '%assetid%', 219890, 16, 0 )",
            "name": "Turn into Gems..."
          }
        ],
        ... [truncated]
```

So there's a sole child called the inventory ID, which itself has a sole child corresponding to the context ID. That in turn has a sole child called something (I don't know what it corresponds to), and inside of that is the same `owner_actions` we saw earlier (among other things).

From there it's pretty easy to find that link, parse out the `appid` and `item_type`, and make the web request to find the gem value of that item.

**Something to watch out for:** you can't just select the link of the first object in `owner_actions`:

- There can be more than one action in there, such as the "View badge progress" action for trading cards.
- The "Turn into Gems..." action doesn't show up on items that don't have gem values.
- Sometimes `g_rgAssets` doesn't have `owner_actions` at all.

The bookmarklet above has some rudimentary handling for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the `appID` of the game, e.g. `239350` for *[Spelunky](https://store.steampowered.com/app/239350/Spelunky/)*.

[image: appID]

2. Check the gem amount corresponding to a **normal card** (`item_type=2`) at:

> https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=239350&item_type=2

[image: normal card]

3. Check the gem amount corresponding to a **foil card** (`item_type=2`, `border_color=1`) at:

> https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=239350&item_type=2&border_color=1

[image: foil card]

4. Check the gem amount corresponding to an **emoticon** (`item_type=10`) at:

> https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=239350&item_type=10

[image: emoticon]

5. Check the gem amount corresponding to a **profile background** (`item_type=17`) at:

> https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=239350&item_type=17

[image: profile background]

**Caveat**: `item_type` numbering can differ from one game to another:

- the index of the first card is always 2,
- the index of the first emoticon can change depending on the number of cards,
- the index of the first profile background can change depending on the number of cards, the number of emoticons, and the existence of gaps in the numbering [for unknown reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889254/376454).

So, adjust accordingly and check the other values if you have any doubt.

Comment: It seems like the index of the first card isn't always 2 for all games, for example if you run the javascript script provided by @jkmartindale [here](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/338840-Snowing%20Land) you'll see that a profile background has an item_type of 2.